# Reducing the size of a QMdiSubWindow holding a QLabel with QPixmap

Tags: qt

The question statement says it all. I am able to enlarge the QMdiSubWindow (and the pixmap scales UP, i.e. enlarges, appropriately) but I am not able to reduce its size (i.e. scale the image DOWN or shrink). When trying to scale down though, the border handles of the QMdiSubWindow remain rigidly fixed.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
class PixmapWidget :  public QLabel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    PixmapWidget():
    QLabel()
    {
        _pixmap = QPixmap("path\\to\\image.jpg");
        setPixmap(_pixmap);            
        _layout = new QHBoxLayout();
        _layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);
        setLayout(_layout);
        setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred));
    }

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
    {
        int width = event->size().width();
        int height = event->size().height();
        setPixmap(_pixmap.scaled(width,height));
        QLabel::resizeEvent(event);
    }

protected:
    QPixmap _pixmap;
    QHBoxLayout* _layout;
};

int main()
{
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    QHBoxLayout*  layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QMdiArea* mdiArea = new QMdiArea();

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(mdiArea);
    mainWindow.centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
    layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);

    QMdiSubWindow* mdiSubWindow = new QMdiSubWindow();
    layout->addWidget(mdiSubWindow);        
    mdiSubWindow->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred));
    mdiSubWindow->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);

    DMSQt::PixmapWidget pixmapWidget;        
    mdiSubWindow->layout()->addWidget(&pixmapWidget);

    mainWindow.show();
    qapp.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem. Apparently, I need to set a minimum size on my text label:

Adding:

```
setMinimumSize(_pixmap.width(), _pixmap.height());
```

solved the problem.